# Graph dates in R

Tags: r

I have a database and I need to graph dates in R(Rstudio)
It is like:

```
Name    01/01/2018  01/02/2018  01/03/2018  ....

Adam       0            4            3
Adler      1            3            5
Alvin      0            5            9
```

How can I graph the evolution in Adler's data in R? Thank you

Comment: How about transposing the data to make time as a column and then plot the Adam column as a time-series?

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes the code you have so far, and a clear sense of what you're trying to do. It's unclear now how exactly you want to plot this—bar chart? line chart? What packages are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidy version:

```r
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, check.names = FALSE, text = "
Name    01/01/2018  01/02/2018  01/03/2018
Adam       0            4            3
Adler      1            3            5
Alvin      0            5            9")

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
as_tibble(dat) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Name, names_to = "Date") %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(Date, value, color = Name)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: sample ggplot2]